# Half quadratic splitting (alternating optimization with penalty)

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Hello I'm working on an optimization problem:

$$\hat{x}=\text{arg min}_{x} \frac{1}{2}\parallel y - Hx \parallel^{2} + \lambda \Phi (x), \quad x, y \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times M}.$$

where $H$ is a matrix and $\Phi$ an application.

To solve this problem, my idea is to split in two subproblems like in ADMM (http://stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/admm_distr_stats.pdf).

The problem of minimizating the before equation is equivalent to

$$\hat{x}=\text{arg min} _{x} \frac{1}{2}\parallel y - Hx \parallel^{2} + \lambda \Phi (z)\quad \text{s.t.}\quad z=x, \qquad z, x \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times M}.$$

The method of HQS (half splitting quadratic) seeks to minizmize the following cost function:

$$L_{\mu}(x,z) = \frac{1}{2}\parallel y-Hx\parallel^{2} +\lambda \Phi(z) + \frac{\mu}{2} \parallel z-x\parallel^{2}, \qquad z, x \in \mathbb{R}^{N\times M}, \mu\in\mathbb{R^{+}} .$$

And we apply the HQS method, that solves it iterativetely:

\begin{equation}
 \left\{
 \begin{aligned}
 x_{k+1} &= \text{arg min} _{x} {\frac{1}{2}}\parallel {y-}Hx \parallel^{2} + \mu \parallel x-z_{k}\parallel^{2}, \\[1pt]
   z_{k+1} &= \text{arg min} _{z} \frac{\mu}{2} \parallel z-x_{k+1}\parallel^{2} + \lambda \Phi (z).
\end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation}

My question is: Is this equivalent to the original problem? for convergence and obtaining a solution of the original problem, what do we have to supose about $\mu$?

And the most important, which convergence results are there? Any textbook to learn this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's $\Phi$?  Is $\Phi$ differentiable?  Does it have an easy prox-operator?

Comment: This problem arises in the context of image restoration. $\Phi$ would be the prior of the image, the regularization term (and $H$ a blur operator). I'm trying to avoid using $\Phi$ in an explicit way by using a denoising function.
For my answer theres no assumptions about $\Phi$ let's be the more general possible to understand the essence of this problem.

Comment: It's obviously true in the limit as $\mu \rightarrow \infty$, because the penalty term will inflate any difference between $x$ and $z$; forcing them to be the same.

According to Proposition 11 in [this](http://rutcor.rutgers.edu/pub/rrr/reports2012/32_2012.pdf) review paper, the ADMM method converges to the optimal solution.

Comment: what you have written is a penalty method and not ADMM (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_method). For normal penalty methods, you need to take the penalty weight, i.e. $\mu$, to infinity over the course of the iterates in order to converge. In your case, it is also block-wise update. I do not think the block-wise update would change the convergence. But proving it might be more difficult [what you are doing is similar to alternating projection when $\mu\rightarrow \infty$]. 
But why don't you use ADMM [which uses augmented Lagrangian instead of simple penalty objective]?

Comment: Ryan Warnick: That's the point, it would be equivalent as $\mu\to\infty$ but in the review paper I said tells that if the penalty parameter is too big, the solution it can be not very optimal (because you give more weight to the strained). And the paper you said, the proposition of convergences tells about a $c>0$ and in this case converges to the optimal of the original problem, it doesn´t move the penalty parameter. So.. it is okay to have a fixed penalty?

Comment: Maziar Sanjabi: yes, it not exactly the ADMM. I found it as HQS. Are they not equivalent in such way? And you tells about $\mu\to\infty$ for convergence but in all paper I read tells about a fixed positive $\mu$ why?

Comment: They are not equivalent for fixed $\mu$.